# Trying to parse JSON in Swift 3 using Alamofire

Tags: ios, json, swift, swift3, alamofire

I am using Alamofire to call my API which returns the following JSON:

```
{
    outer =         {
        height = 3457;
        width = 2736;
    };
    cost = 220;
    name = "Mega";
},
    {
    outer =         {
        height = 275;
        width = 300;
    };
    cost = 362;
    name = "Ultra";
},
```

I want to for example get the names and the heights and store them into arrays.

Here is the relevant code i am using to get the height:

```
 if let url = URL(string: "LINKTOAPI") {
        var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
        urlRequest.httpMethod = HTTPMethod.get.rawValue
        urlRequest.addValue(apiKey, forHTTPHeaderField: "user-key")
        urlRequest.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

        Alamofire.request(urlRequest).responseJSON {response in
            if let result = response.result.value as? [String:Any],
                let main = result["outer"] as? [[String:String]]{
                for obj in main{
                    print(obj["height"])                       
                }
            }
 }
```

Another example below:

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41462844/json-parsing-in-swift-3-using-alamofire](http://%22=%22%20example)

My attempt with the relevant code using the above example:

```
 Alamofire.request(urlRequest).responseJSON {response in
            if let jsonDict = response.result.value as? [String:Any],
                let dataArray = jsonDict["outer"] as? [[String:Any]] {
                let nameArray = dataArray.flatMap { $0["height"] as? String }
                print(nameArray)
            }
```

In BOTH examples, literally nothing prints so im not sure what is wrong. Any advice appreciated

EDIT: Full JSON below

```
SUCCESS: (
        {
    outer =         {
        height = 3457;
        width = 2736;
    };
    cost = 220;
    name = "Mega";
 },
        {
    outer =         {
        height = 275;
        width = 300;
    };
    cost = 362;
    name = "Ultra";
 },
        {
    outer =         {
        height = 31;
        width = 56;
    };
    cost = 42;
    name = "Mini";
 }
)
```

Comment: Please **read** the output (better read the real JSON output). Braces `{}` are always dictionaries. And the Swift collection type output does not reveal unambiguously if `height` and `width` are `Int`s or `String`s. The parent object (not shown in the output) seems to be an array.

Comment: You are not showing the whole JSON structure, so it's hard to help.  Strictly from what you have shown, your parser is going to fail for many reasons.  Firstly, `jsonDict` seems to be an array of dictionaries, so `[[String : Any]]`.  Secondly, the `outer` object within each dictionary is NOT an array, so should be `[String : Any]`.  That means that there's no need to `flatMap` over `dataArray` since it's not an array at all.

Comment: @creeperspeak This is the whole exact JSON structure that gets returned from my API call. If i make jsonDict [[String:Any]] and outer [String:Any], then it gives me an error saying "Cannot subscript a value of type '[[String : Any]]' with an index of type 'String'"

Comment: I know it’s not a whole JSON structure because it is split in half by a comma and ends with another comma. And you can’t subscript an array with a string - the error is correct.

Comment: @creeperspeak. Technically you are right, i omitted the unnecessary stuff that comes with the API call. This is the format, all i did was exclude an open parenthesis at the top and close parenthesis at the bottom. There are also a few more JSON blocks as shown in the original post but they are in the same format and i excluded them because they were redundant. The point is, this is the JSON format. Do you have any possible solutions to get the desired output? I have tried following every example i can find on SO and none seem to work.

Comment: I will write you an answer to tell you exactly how to do it because I'm a nice guy, but in the future keep in mind that ALL that stuff is relevant!  Removing brackets is huge when you are parsing JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments I understand that the structure actually looks like this:

```
[{
    outer =         {
        height = 3457;
        width = 2736;
    };
    cost = 220;
    name = "Mega";
},
    {
    outer =         {
        height = 275;
        width = 300;
    };
    cost = 362;
    name = "Ultra";
}]
```

I still don't fully understand what you are hoping to do with all these variables, but here is how you parse them to print the `height` value for each section, as that is what you seem to be trying to do in the examples:

```
//Here you safely unwrap all of the sections as an array of dictionaries
if let allSections = response.result.value as? [[String : Any]] {

    //Here we will loop through the array and parse each dictionary
    for section in allSections {
        if let cost = section["cost"] as? Int, let name = section["name"] as? String, let outer = section["outer"] as? [String : Any], let height = outer["height"] as? Int, let width = outer["width"] as? Int {
            //Inside here you have access to every attribute in the section

            print(height)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a ton for the help. I will have to compare your solution to all of my previous attempts to see what i was doing wrong.

Comment: Do you know how i can access those values such as "cost" and "name" outside this file. I want to access them from a different file but they are limited to the scope of the if statement i believe

Comment: Well normally you'd create an object (a class or a struct) to represent that object after you parse it from your API call, and then you create instances of these objects for the sake of using them in your app.